# Why is this Angular routing leading to a 404 "Not Found" page?

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angular-ui-router

In this example,  clicking any of the 3 anchor links instantly routes to a 404 "Not Found" page.  -I.e., instead of inserting html text into the `<div ng-view></div>`

What is incorrect (or missing) that would enable this code to work properly?  (syntax, path, etc.)

(I'm confounded!)

Thanks for your help!

*(I'm new to AngularJS, and its clear that I lack experience to pick out the issue)*

***the initial html page displays like this...***

[image]

***...this is the result of clicking "testA"*** *(note the URL change)*

[image]

index.jsp

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="mainApp">
        <head>
            <title>mywebapp</title>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <base href="/"> 

            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>  
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>    
            <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webjars/angularjs/1.3.13/angular-route.js"></script>   

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);

                mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

                    alert('mywebapp - $routeProvider=' + JSON.stringify($routeProvider));

                    $routeProvider    
                        .when('/', {
                            templateUrl : 'resources/pages/home.html',
                            controller  : 'MainController'
                        })                
                        .when('/testA', {
                            templateUrl : 'resources/pages/testA.html',
                            controller  : 'TestAController'
                        })
                        .when('/testB', {
                            templateUrl : 'resources/pages/testB.html',
                            controller  : 'TestBController'
                        })
                        .when('/testC', {
                            templateUrl : 'resources/pages/testC.html',
                            controller  : 'TestCController'
                        });
                });

                mainApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
                    alert('MainController...');
                    $scope.message = 'HOME page.';
                });

                mainApp.controller('TestAController', function ($scope) {
                    alert('TestAController...');
                    $scope.message = 'TestA page.';
                });

                mainApp.controller('TestBController', function ($scope) {
                    alert('TestBController...');
                    $scope.message = 'TestB page.';
                });

                mainApp.controller('TestCController', function ($scope) {
                    alert('TestCController...');
                    $scope.message = 'TestC page.';
                });
            </script>
        </head>

        <body ng-controller="MainController">
            <input type="hidden" id="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />    
            <div>
                <h4>select a page destination...</h4>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#/testA">TestA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/testB">TestB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/testC">TestC</a></li>                  
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="main">
                    <div ng-view></div>
                </div>     
            </div>              
        </body>
    </html>
```

---

---

### BELOW IS MORE DETAILED INFORMATION IF YOU LIKE...(THX)

---

home.html (fragment)

```
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>HOME Page</h1>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
```

testA.html (fragment)

```
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>TestA Page</h1>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
```

testB.html (fragment)

```
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>TestB Page</h1>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
```

testC.html (fragment)

```
    <div class="jumbotron text-center">
        <h1>TestC Page</h1>
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
                 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
                 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                 xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
                 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
                 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
                 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                 xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
                 xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
                 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
                 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
                 xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd   
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd     
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd    
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd     
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd     
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task      http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd                                
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd                                
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
                                    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core          http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
                                    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

        <beans:bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/app" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="aaa.bbb.ccc.**" />    

        <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentManager"/>
        <beans:bean id="contentManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
            <beans:property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
            <beans:property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
            <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
                <beans:map>
                    <beans:entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                    <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                    <beans:entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                </beans:map>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
        <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />    

    </beans:beans>
```

web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
             version="3.1">

        <filter>
            <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
                <param-value>true</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>charEncodingFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
        </listener>    

        <listener>
            <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
        </listener>    

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </context-param>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>
                    WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml           
                </param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

    </web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>aaa.bbb.ccc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>mywebapp</name>
        <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

        <properties>
            <org.springframework.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>        
            <org.springframework.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>            
            <java.version>1.7</java.version>
            <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
            <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
            <jsp-api.version>2.1</jsp-api.version>
            <javax.servlet.jsp.version>2.3.1</javax.servlet.jsp.version>            
            <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
            <jackson-databind.version>2.3.4</jackson-databind.version>
            <jackson.mapper.version>1.9.13</jackson.mapper.version>        
            <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
            <org.slf4j.version>1.7.7</org.slf4j.version>        
            <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
            <commons-codec.version>1.9</commons-codec.version>
            <datatables.version>1.10.4</datatables.version>
            <angularjs.version>1.3.13</angularjs.version>                   

        </properties>

        <dependencies>

            <!-- Unit Testing -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Servlet 3.1   -->      
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.servlet.jsp.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>${jstl.version}</version>
            </dependency>   

            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
            </dependency>    

            <!-- Spring Security -->       
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>    

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
                <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JSON jackson for spring         -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.mapper.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- @Inject -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Logging -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>        

            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-codec.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>datatables</artifactId>
                <version>${datatables.version}</version>
            </dependency>   

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
                <version>${angularjs.version}</version>
            </dependency>                      

        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>    

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                </plugin> 

            </plugins>
        </build>

    </project>
```

project structure...

[image]

Comment: Make the links `href="#/testA"` and the main route `.when("/", {..}`

Comment: Hi New Dev.  I posted your suggested changes - as I understood them.  And, I've test them, but, they have not fixed the issue.   Please let me know if I overlooked something.   -thx  again

Answer (score 2):

it appears that the "culprit" is the frikkin `<base>` tag.  -When removed, all works as expected.   (whew!...-although, a bit embarrassing)

i.e.,

```
    <head>
        <title>mywebapp</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <base href="/">  (**WORKS AFTER REMOVING THIS LINE**)
```

Comment: Ah, I missed the `<base>` tag. It was incorrectly set - your base should be: `/mywebbapp/`, but it was set to `/`. In any case, [read the section about HTML5 vs. Hashbang mode](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes)

Answer (score 0):

I see that all your requests are being passed to Spring MVC:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Your next configuration seems that /resources/** is being resolved to /resources... which it seems correct but innecesary:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

However... this tag tells Spring to add a prefix+suffix which maybe is causing your problem:

```
<beans:bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/app" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

I recommend you to map only .htm requests to Spring MVC and leave the rest request to be resolved by the server (as static resources).

Try the next changes:

1) change the servlet mapping to *.htm (this foces that ONLY urls like index.htm will be processed by Spring MVC):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

2) include index.htm (with no "l") as welcome page (so /# will be mapped to /index.htm#/, so... the welcome page will be processed as jsp):

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Thank you, Carlos.   I will take your advice to heart.   However, the immediate issue is apparently caused by the <base> tag.  when removed, the app worked as expected.

Comment: Lol... I haven't seen that.. base tag is used to "simulate" that you are in another server, it's useful to work in a local file but... sometimes is a pain (like this situation).

Answer (score 0):

try removing hashtags from your routes

```
<body ng-controller="MainController">
        <input type="hidden" id="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />    
        <div>
            <h4>select a page destination...</h4>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/testA">TestA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/testB">TestB</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/testC">TestC</a></li>                  
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>     
        </div>              
    </body>
```

try using this way to instance your routes

```
angular.module('yourApp').config(function ($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state('route', {
    url: '/route/in/url/you/want/to/use', //after your proyect url 
    templateUrl: 'resources/app/statistics/statistics.html', //html for this 

//route
    controller: 'statisticsController', //controller for this route
    controllerAS: 'statisticsController' //the way you gona call this 

//controller(this replace scope in html only for this controller)

  })
});
```